# How to print strings from an array that contain the letter 'z'?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I need to write a Java program that prints out all the strings (from a given array) that contain the letter `z`? I need to do it without using the function `.contains`.

My code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Program prints out all the words with common letter:");
    String[] strArr = {"computers", "information systems", "test"};
    System.out.println(Lettercheck(strArr , 'x'));
    
}

public static void Lettercheck(String[] strArr , char ch) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: z or x? Your code does not match your prose.

Comment: `Lettercheck()` should be returning a value like a `boolean`, for a start.

Comment: You can use `strArr[i].indexOf(ch) >= 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the .charAt() function, this return the current character in String.

eg.

```
String a = "Hello";
System.out.println(a.charAt(0));
```

This will give you 'H' as output.
So your code should look something like this:

```
public static void Lettercheck(String[] strArr , char ch) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
        for( int j=0; j<strArr[i].length();j++){
             if(strArr[i].charAt(j)==ch)
                  System.out.println(strArr[i]);
                  break; 
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Your code breaks with most characters. See demo of problem [run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/OSvnFB). `System.out.println( "Hello".charAt(0) );` yields invalid character.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
Can I just ask you how'd I print out all the words? For example with the letter 'z'? 
I tried to use - system.out.println(Lettercheck(strArr , 'z'); 
but it won't work

Comment: You can just call the function and print inside the function one by one. so instead of system.out.println(Lettercheck(strArr , 'z')); you write Lettercheck(strArr , 'z'). and use the code I wrote, it will print them all.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```java
List
    .of( "computers" , "information systems" , "zebra" )
    .stream()
    .filter( 
        input -> input.codePoints().anyMatch( codePoint -> codePoint == "z".codePointAt( 0 ) ) 
    ) 
    .toList()
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/rTrabr).

> [zebra]

## Obsolete `char`

The `char` type has been legacy since Java 2, essentially broken. As a 16-bit value, a `char` is physically incapable of representing most characters.

## Code point

Instead, use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers to work with individual characters.

Get the code point number assigned to our targeted letter, `z`, which is 122 decimal.

```java
int targetCodePoint = "z".codePointAt( 0 ); // Get the code point assigned to the letter “z”, 122.
```

Define our inputs, and make a place to put the words/phrases that contain our target letter.

```java
List < String > inputs = List.of( "computers" , "information systems" , "zebra" );
List < String > hits = new ArrayList <>( inputs.size() );
```

Loop each input word/phrase.

```java
for ( String input : inputs )
{
    …
}
```

For each of those inputs, loop the code point of each character in that word/phrase.

Test each code point to see if it matches our target code point (122). If so, remember this word by adding to our `hits` list, and then bail out of the inner loop (the code points loop).

```java
loopingInputs:
for ( String input : inputs )
{
    // Loop the code point of each character.
    int[] codePoints = input.codePoints().toArray();
    for ( int codePoint : codePoints )
    {
        if ( codePoint == targetCodePoint )  
        {
            hits.add( input );
            break loopingInputs;
        }
    }
}
```

Dump results to console.

```java
System.out.println( "hits = " + hits );
```

See this code run live at IdeOne.com.

> hits = [zebra]

We can slim down this code to be more compact by using streams and lambdas. See the `tl;dr` section at top.